# Deserializing IEnumerable with private backing field in RavenDb

Tags: ravendb

I've been modeling a domain for a couple of days now and not been thinking at all at persistance but instead focusing on domain logic. Now I'm ready to persist my domain objects, some of which contains IEnumerable of child entities. Using RavenDb, the persistance is 'easy', but when loading my objects back again, all of the IEnumerables are empty.

I've realized this is because they don't have any property setters at all, but instead uses a list as a backing field. The user of the domain aggregate root can add child entities through a public method and not directly on the collection.

```
private readonly List<VeryImportantPart> _veryImportantParts;
public IEnumerable<VeryImportantPart> VeryImportantParts { get { return _veryImportantParts; } }
```

And the method for adding, nothing fancy...

```
public void AddVeryImportantPart(VeryImportantPart part)
{
    // some logic...
    _veryImportantParts.Add(part);
}
```

I can fix this by adding a private/protected setter on all my IEnumerables with backing fields but it looks... well... not super sexy.

```
private List<VeryImportantPart> _veryImportantParts;
public IEnumerable<VeryImportantPart> VeryImportantParts
{
    get { return _veryImportantParts; }
    protected set { _veryImportantParts = value.ToList(); }
}
```

Now the RavenDb json serializer will populate my objects on load again, but I'm curious if there isn't a cleaner way of doing this?

I've been fiddeling with the *JsonContractResolver* but haven't found a solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the root cause of this issue and it's probably due to the fact that many of my entities were created using:

```
protected MyClass(Guid id, string name, string description) : this()
{ .... }

public static MyClass Create(string name, string description)
{
    return new MyClass(Guid.NewGuid(), name, description);
}
```

When deserializing, RavenDb/Json.net couldn't rebuild my entities in a proper way...

Changing to using a public constructor made all the difference.

Comment: You can keep also try just adding a private or protected parameterless constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Do you *need* to keep a private backing field?  Often an automatic property will do.

```
public IList<VeryImportantPart> VeryImportantParts { get; protected set; }
```

When doing so, you may want to initialize your list in the constructor:

```
VeryImportantParts = new List<VeryImportantPart>();
```

This is optional, of course, but it allows you to create a new class and start adding to the list right away, before it is persisted.  When Raven deserializes a class, it will use the setter to overwrite the default blank list, so this just helps with the first store.

You certainly won't be able to use a `readonly` field, as it couldn't be replaced during deserialization.  It *might* be possible to write a contract resolver or converter that fills an existing list rather than creating a new one, but that seems like a rather complex solution.

Using an automatic property can add clarity to your code anyway - as it is less confusing whether to use the field or the property.

Comment: Well, I don't really want to expose the IList to the "user" of this domain object to do as it pleases but instead use a more intention-revealing interface, as Jimmy Bogard describes here http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/10/strengthening-your-domain-encapsulated-collections/

Comment: Yes, that can be desired sometimes.  Unfortunately, it's hard to reveal in one form but deserialize in another.  How you described adding a protected or private setter is one solution. Another would be to have an automatic private property and reveal using a method, such as `public IEnumerable GetVeryImportantParts()`